# Django: How to filter DB records by 0-3 criteria?

Tags: python, django

My goal is to have a search form (currently with 3 fields, but later possibly with more) which could be used for filtering products (In my case a product is `training` that can be filtered by `sport`, `province` and `city`). All those filter fields shall be optional, so I want to ignore when the POST value is either **None** (`sport` and `province` are FKs to related tables) or an **empty string** (`city`).

I need to chain those three condition into the `Training.objects.filter()` call, but I need to omit conditions, that are not actually used. And I also need to check for **None** values as I am getting `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` exception.

This is what I have so far, but it is not good (only when all 3 conditions are properly filled):

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(sport = searchQuery.sport.sport_id).filter(province = searchQuery.province.province_id).filter(city = searchQuery.city)
```

I tried to use conditional expression inside `filter()` to avoid exceptions, but either I am not able to elaborate the syntax correctly, or it is not possible - I was stopped by invalid syntax error...

I was even thinking of dumb solution checking inputs in IF clauses and have different query for each case, but even with 3 params it has many different options already, so I doubt this is the way when I plan to add more filters later.

Any suggestions? This seems like kinda trivial task to me, but so far I was unable to google the right solution :(

Comment: What is `searchQuery`?

Comment: Object retrieved from the search form after POSTing, so it contains the search criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Queryset is lazy loaded so following is not an issue for it

```
trainings = Training.objects.filter(sport = searchQuery.sport.sport_id)
if something:
    trainings = trainings.filter(province = searchQuery.province.province_id)
```

You don't need to have each separate option depending on a state of your filter variables.

also you can do it by catching exceptions

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could apply filters conditionally:

```
trainings = Training.objects.all()
if searchQuery.sport:
    trainings = trainings.filter(sport=searchQuery.sport)
if searchQuery.province:
    trainings = trainings.filter(province=searchQuery.province)
if searchQuery.city:
    trainings = trainings.filter(city=searchQuery.city)

for training in trainings:  # this will be the point where the actual database call occurs
    # do something
```